# How to detect the fuzzy edge in this image?

Tags: image-processing, image-segmentation, edge-detection

I am trying to process a lot of images of bacteria. As you can see from this image, when several bacterias are very close, the boundary tends to be very fuzzy.

[image]

I try to binary the image or detect the edge use canny operator.But the result is unsatisfying.

So is there a right way to distinguish every cell in this situation?I want both get the right count and position of every cell. Thanks to all of you.

Answer (score 2):

bacteria segmentation is a broad field with many approaches. here's an [example](https://bmcbioinformatics.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1471-2105-15-251). For your spesific image, I think you can do the following tricks:

```
d=double(imread('bac.png'));
d=d./max(d(:));

ws=7; % window size 
mean_d=imfilter(d,fspecial('average',ws),'replicate'); % this is a local mean operation 
d2=d-mean_d;

d3 = conv2(d2.*(d2>0), fspecial('laplacian',0),'same');
subplot(3,1,1);imagesc(d);colorbar
subplot(3,1,2);imagesc(d2);colorbar
subplot(3,1,3);imagesc(d3);colorbar
```

you can take it from there...
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you have already tried kind of edge detector - you should pay attention *Hysteresis* for Canny -

Second, you can try to image enhancement technique which name is **Histogram Equalization**. Histogram equalization makes darker parts more more darker and brighter parts will be more brighter. Then you can apply Canny or adaptive threshold to detect these bacterias.